# .net core WebAPI enable SSL for intranet

Tags: ssl, iis, .net-core, ssl-certificate, webapi

I am new to the SSL stuff, and developing WebApi .net core 3.0 that will be consumed by react (both hosted on same webserver-IIS 10 on 443 port).

Can you tell be very clear and detailed steps to make it work

1. The DNS mapping is done and WebApi and react app both are hosted on IIS, but when API is being called from react it is giving error **ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**
2. Dev and Test server will not have an actual certificate, so what settings I should do (how should I
   generate cert and add on IIS?)
3. I've followed some blogs/videos but, I am missing or doing something wrong.

Comment: Is this one of the articles you have tried? https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html

Comment: thanks, I tried already, but its not working, may be something else in .netcore 3 or IIS 10?
Also - what should I do for Intranet SSL? the DNS mapping have been done.

Comment: Learn how to force Windows/browsers to trust self-signed certificates, and then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a self-signed certificate in iis you can try one the below way:

1)using GUI

- open iis manager
- Click on the server name in the Connections column on the left and Double-click on Server Certificates

[image]

- Click on Create Self-Signed Certificate in the Actions Column on the right.

[image]

- Type any meaningful name and then click OK to proceed

[image]

- Click OK. Once that is complete you should now see the SSL in the list of Self-Signed certificates.

2)using command prompt

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName www.domain.com -CertStoreLocation cert:Localmachine\My
```

You could also try  to move the certificate to the trusted root by following below steps:

1)open mmc.exe as administrator.

2)In the MMC Console, in the top menu, click File > Add/Remove Snap-in….

[image]

3)In the Add or Remove Snap-ins windows, in the Available snap-ins: section, select Certificates and then click Add >.

[image]

4)In the Certificate snap-in window, select Computer account and then click Next.

[image]

5)In the Add or Remove Snap-ins window, you should now see the Certificates (Local Computer) snap-in.

[image]

6)Click OK

7)In the MMC Console, in the console tree, expand Certificates (Local Computer) > Personal, and select the Certificates folder.

[image]

8)In the center pane, select the certificate that you want to move.

9)Right-click on the certificate and click Copy.

[image]

10)now Expand Trust Root Certification Authorities, certificate folder.

[image]

11)right-click on the middle pane and paste certificate.

If you have a certificate already then you can import and set it at the trusted root store by following below article:

[How to trust the IIS Express Self-Signed Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/robert_mcmurray/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate)

Comment: Thanks for such detail steps, I'll delete all existing self signed certificates and try again.
BUT, I doubt by doing this it will solve Point 2 - **How to do SSL** for Intranet webApi

Comment: @Praveen if you want to host the site on internet it is best practice to use a trusted ca certificate. you need to purchase domain name public IP and the certificate.

Comment: I am looking for INTRANET certificate, if this is Internet so I would have been easier for me also :)
Any idea about intranet SSL with iis 10 and .net core so please share.

Comment: @Praveen you will always get an error. you need to purchase trusted CA certificate.

Comment: agree, but I read it somewhere that- CA doesn't provides certificates for INTRANET sites,

Comment: @Praveen you could try to move the certificate to the active directory. please refer  this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/906015/how-to-setup-ssl-certs-for-a-lan-web-app-server and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy